# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: joomla, php

Всем привет! Имеется сайт на joomla, с недавних времен стала появляться такая вот штука:

**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/users2/n/user/domains/yamarka.ru/components/com_virtuemart/helpers/vmsmallhelper.php on line 17**

используется плагин virtuemart, данный warning выводится в выводе товаров

Comment: Напишите им в поддержку и скачивайте выходящие обновления. Можно, конечно, вручуную править и разбираться, но лучше, когда это правится на стороне разработчика.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте отключить ошибки в настройках http://screencast.com/t/UDeqMf4GU

а сама ошибка нам говорит, что в конструкцию foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) передается какой то другой тип, но не массив

```
if(is_array($arr)) {
    if(count($arr)) {
        foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
        }
    }
}
```